# Calling a method in the middle of a another one prevents following variables from being set - Laravel job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a Laravel Job which sets some data and then uses the data to create an entry in the database. All the fields in the database table are `NULL`able. There's the `custom_variables` field - set using a custom method `getByPrefix()`.

**MyJob.php**

```
<?php

class MyJob implements ShouldQueue {

    public function __construct($input) {
        $this->input = $input;
    }

    public function handle() {

        $data = $this->getData();

        MyModel::create($data);

    }

    protected function getData() {

        if (isset($this->input['name'])) {
            $data['name'] = $this->input['name'];
        }


        $data['custom_variables'] = $this->getByPrefix('custom-');

        if (isset($this->input['surname'])) {
            $data['surname'] = $this->input['surname'];
        }

        return $data;
    }


    /**
     * Filter the input by the provided prefix 
     * and return matching input data.
     * @return null|string
     */
    protected function getByPrefix($prefix) {

        $this->input= array_filter($this->input, function($k) use ($prefix) {
            return strpos($k, $prefix) !== false;
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

        if (count($this->input) === 0) {
            return null;
        }

        $data = array();

        foreach ($this->inputas $k => $v) {
            array_push($data, array($k => $v));
        }

        if (empty($data)) {
            return null;
        }

        return json_encode($data);

    }
```

}

**The problem** is that if I keep the call to `getByPrefix()` in the middle, then the value of `$data['surname']` is always `NULL` when the record is stored, even if the `surname` is present in the input.

When I move the call to `getByPrefix()` to the end of the script, the `$data['surname']` is set properly.

**Why is this happening?** Is it because I *might* return JSON from the `getByPrefix()` method? Don't think so, but who knows.

I tried wrapping the body of `getByPrefix()` in a `try-catch` - but there are no errors whatsoever, and the `custom_variables` field is always set in the DB.

Any idea what might be happening here?

**Update**

Example input data:

```
array(
    'name' => 'John', 
    'surname' => 'Doe', 
    'custom-var' => 'customValue'
)
```

Output (after `getByPrefix()` is applied):

```
array(
    'name' => 'John', 
    'custom_variables' => "[{"custom-var":"customValue"}]"
)
```

Comment: show us a var_dump() of $data

Comment: @delboy1978uk Updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of this part:

```
$this->input= array_filter($this->input, function($k) use ($prefix) {
        return strpos($k, $prefix) !== false;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

You are filtering your input and overwritting the results to it. Try using another variable.

```
 $input= array_filter($this->input, function($k) use ($prefix) {
        return strpos($k, $prefix) !== false;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

The reason you are getting `name` but not `surname` is simply because you set name before calling the method, while the later is set after.

Comment: Yep, just figured it out. Still, it took you 10x less time than me :)

Comment: It's easier to debug others code... Don't forget to change your variable in the foreach right after...